# Why does bash $LINENO change inside an inner block in a function?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm trying to debug auto completion script located in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` (bash completion package on every distro)
I did

```
export PS4='+'$'\t''$LINENO'$'\t    # \t for proper indentation
set -x
```

in the **current shell**, then typed a command (following by space), and pressed tab to call auto completion.
This is a part of the result:

```bash
+       2205    for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
+       24      [[ -d /usr/share/bash-completion/completions ]]
+       2207    for compfile in "$cmd" "$cmd.bash" "_$cmd"
+       26      compfile=/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/bittch
+       28      [[ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/bittch ]]
+       2207    for compfile in "$cmd" "$cmd.bash" "_$cmd"
```

As you see the first line number is `2205` which is the absolute line number inside the script. Surprisingly, the number of the next line (which is a nested block) is `24`, that is the line number relative to the function itself (see below)

```bash
__load_completion()
{
    local -a dirs=(${BASH_COMPLETION_USER_DIR:-${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/bash-completion}/completions)
    local ifs=$IFS IFS=: dir cmd="${1##*/}" compfile
    [[ -n $cmd ]] || return 1
    for dir in ${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share}; do
        dirs+=($dir/bash-completion/completions)
    done
    IFS=$ifs

    if [[ $BASH_SOURCE == */* ]]; then
        dirs+=("${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/completions")
    else
        dirs+=(./completions)
    fi

    local backslash=
    if [[ $cmd == \\* ]]; then
        cmd="${cmd:1}"
        # If we already have a completion for the "real" command, use it
        $(complete -p "$cmd" 2>/dev/null || echo false) "\\$cmd" && return 0
        backslash=\\
    fi
    for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
        [[ -d $dir ]] || continue
        for compfile in "$cmd" "$cmd.bash" "_$cmd"; do
            compfile="$dir/$compfile"
            # Avoid trying to source dirs; https://bugzilla.redhat.com/903540
            if [[ -f $compfile ]] && . "$compfile" &>/dev/null; then
                [[ $backslash ]] && $(complete -p "$cmd") "\\$cmd"
                return 0
            fi
        done
    done

    # Look up simple "xspec" completions
    [[ -v _xspecs[$cmd] ]] &&
        complete -F _filedir_xspec "$cmd" "$backslash$cmd" && return 0

    return 1
}
```

I know that `LINENO` represents [The line number in the script or shell function currently executing.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) But these are in the same function, so either both should be relative (to the beginning of `__load_completion()`) or absolute.
Why is this?

Comment: It looks like it depends on the kind of statement. control-flow statements (e.g. `for`) get absolute line numbers, ordinary statements get relative.

Comment: @Barmar It makes sense, but this behavior is undesired I believe. At least it's not documented. I'll go through source code this weekend.

Comment: I wasn't trying to explain it, just noticing a pattern.